# Insert Values in Database with id auto increment

Tags: php, mysql, post

I want to upload an image to the database and add the values id, markerID (String, not unique), imagename (text), note (text) and likes (int) to my table pinboard.

This is my php Scirpt:

```
if (isset($_POST["image"]) && isset($_POST["markerID"])) {
    $data = $_POST["image"];
    $markerID = $_POST["markerID"];
    $ImageName = $id.".png";
    $filePath = "CEimages/".$ImageName;
    echo "file ".$filePath;

    if (file_exists($filePath)) {
        unlink($filePath); //delete old file
    }

    $myfile = fopen($filePath, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    file_put_contents($filePath, base64_decode($data));

    //id, markerId, image, note, likes
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO pinboard VALUES ('', '{$markerID}', '{$ImageName}', '', '')") or die ('Could not save entry: '.mysql_error());
}
```

The problem is where I set $ImageName. I want the ImageName to be equal to the id so it is uniqe. But the id is set later, when I add the values (id is auto increment).
How can I set the ImageName to the ID, if the row is insertet in the same script?

Comment: if the image name is equal to the id, why even store it at all?

Comment: what does `$ImageName = $id.".png";` do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Insert record with out image name than after update image path

get your last id `mysql_insert_id();`

Comment: Thank you, new code:
`if (isset($_POST["image"])) {
 $data = $_POST["image"];
 $markerID = $_POST["markerID"];
 
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO pinboard VALUES ('', '{$markerID}', '', '', '')");

 $id = mysql_insert_id();
 $ImageName = $id.".png";
 $filePath = "CEimages/".$ImageName;
 echo "file ".$filePath;

 if (file_exists($filePath)) {
  unlink($filePath);
 }

 $myfile = fopen($filePath, "w");
 file_put_contents($filePath, base64_decode($data));

 mysql_query("UPDATE pinboard SET image ='$ImageName' WHERE id='$id'");
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last inserted id using `mysql_insert_id()` before the insert query and then you can increment it and save it as image name.

However, this isn't the ideal way if your application has multiple operations running at once.

Also, you should use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql.